# Symfony 2 Post/Redirect/Get pattern redirect to HTTPS issue

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I'm using the PRG pattern in Symfony 2 to avoid showing 'Confirm Form Resubmission" page after clicking back button. Everything works fine when the site is on http:// but when the site (production) is on https:// this pattern is not working and the 'Confirm Form Resubmission' appears again :(

Basically I have pages A,B,C.

A: Form

B: Process the form and redirect 303 to C

C: Display some page

I'm making redirection in Symfony like this:

```
return $this->redirect('confirmation', 303);
```

and in the routes for all actions I'm including:

```
schemes="https", host="%secured_host_name%"
```

How can I redirect to make it work on HTTPS:// too ?

Comment: hey, can You check my answer? You solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since redirects are using absolute URIs, one has to take care about proxy servers (HTTP->HTTPS) and reverse proxy servers. If your application is such that a user uses an SSL tunnel to reach your site, this can cause problems also. (You may be able to use the Referer header to discover the domain and port the user is actually entering.)

Solution: Add your proxy to `trusted_proxies` in framework config:

```
# app/config/config.yml
# ...
framework:
    trusted_proxies:  [192.0.0.1, 10.0.0.0/8]
```

or if you don't know your proxy ip:

```
// web/app.php

// ...
Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1', $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
// ...
```